# big image viewer size like 2529x3516

Tags: jquery, image, document, image-viewer

I working on a project where i have one thumbnail of a scan document and then i whant to click on this thumbnail and show the whole big picture of it and the user should pan, zoom etc on it.

The best viewer should be something like a PDF viewer but for images and online in the browser.

The big picture of the document is in sizes like 2529x3516 pixels.

Some ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Create a modal window of the desired size and have its contents the `img` file. Give it `overflow-auto` so the user can pan around and view the whole image at `100%`.

You could also use JavaScript to add `+` and `-` functionality, just adjust the `width` property and let the browser perform the scaling.